# Which CPU/GPU Monero miner for macOS?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, macos, pool-mining

I was wondering what would be the best CPU/GPU Monero/cryptonight miner for MacOS. I have an Intel Core i7 CPU and AMD Radeon 460 GPU.

Comment: I've compiled previous versions of xmr-stak for macOS, but cut out the GPU part since didn't  have a compatible one in system.  I'd think current version should compile just as easy.  They might even have a pre-compiled version for the mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Xmr-stak** is one of the best Monero mining programs and you can easily compile it for macOS. All the necessary instructions are here: [Compile xmr-stak for macOS](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/blob/master/doc/compile_macOS.md).

Comment: Slight reminder, currently you can't compile on macOS 10.14 (Mojave)! There currently is no [CUDA support in 10.14](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042279/cuda-10-and-macos-10-14/)

Comment: If you're interested in Monero mining, you would better take a look at AMD GPUs (so Mac models with them), not Nvidia.

Comment: You can compile it on macOS 10.14 (Mojave) for CPU and AMD GPU mining.